# MacOS route table incomplete IP addresses and masks

Tags: macos, routing, ip-address, ipv4

If you run `netstat -rn` on a Mac (I'm using Mojave 10.14.6 but I suspect this applies to all MacOSs), you get the IP route table, but some of the IP addresses are incomplete, and the netmask column is non-existent:

```
$ netstat -rn
Routing tables



Internet:

Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire

default            192.168.1.1        UGSc          192        0     en0       

127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0       

127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              1      248     lo0       

169.254            link#5             UCS             1        0     en0      !

192.168.1          link#5             UCS             1        0     en0      !

192.168.1.1/32     link#5             UCS             1        0     en0      !

192.168.1.1        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  UHLWIir        68     1450     en0   1144

192.168.1.101      yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy  UHLWI           0        0     en0   1073

192.168.1.103/32   link#5             UCS             0        0     en0      !

224.0.0/4          link#5             UmCS            2        0     en0      !

224.0.0.251        z:z:zz:zz:z:zz      UHmLWI          0        0     en0       

239.255.255.250    1:1:11:11:11:11    UHmLWI          0      540     en0       

255.255.255.255/32 link#5             UCS             0        0     en0      !
```

**How should I interpret the incomplete IP addresses? For example, what is `127`? Should I interpret this as `127.0.0.0`? Is that always the rule - assume that missing octets are 0 and that the displayed octet in the Mac route table is the most significant octet (ie `127` is `127.0.0.0` and not `0.0.0.127`)?**

Also, on Windows (`route print`) and Linux (`route -n`) there is a netmask/genmask column. But since there is no such column on the Mac I'm guessing it is replaced with the CIDR notation within the Destination column (eg `192.168.1.1/32` instead of `192.168.1.1` with a mask of `255.255.255.255`). But then not all routes have the CIDR notation in the Destination column - for example `239.255.255.250` in the above table. **When the slash and following mask are omitted from the IP address in the destination column then are we to assume that the mask is always `0.0.0.0`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of `netstat` that macOS (and maybe other BSD-derived unixes?) comes with uses a somewhat idiosyncratic shorthand for the address and netmask. As you inferred, it uses CIDR notation in the `destination` column rather than having a separate netmask column. But it uses a couple of abbreviations based on the pre-CIDR ["classful" addressing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network) (credit to @grawity for pointing this out and making me look at [the source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-543.260.3/route.tproj/route.c.auto.html) to confirm it).

Short summary: in the old classful system, addresses where the first octet was `0`-`127` (with 0 and 127 being reserved) were "Class A" networks, with a netmask of `255.0.0.0` (what we'd now call `/8`). `128.x`-`191.x` were "Class B" networks, with a netmask of `255.255.0.0` (`/16`). `192.x.x`-`223.x.x` were "Class C" networks, with a netmask of `255.255.255.0` (`/24`). The rest of the address space was "Class D" (for multicast) and "Class E" (reserved), with undefined netmasks. This system was inflexible and inefficient, so it was replaced by Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR) in 1993(!), but vestiges of it live on in various places, including here.

Basically, what `netstat` is doing is to omit things that match what'd be expected under the classful system (and can therefore be inferred from that system). Well, except that it treats Class D and E as having the same implicit netmask as Class C (i.e. `/24`).

- If the address ends with `0` octets where the host portion would be under the old system, it omits those. So, for example, `10/24` is short for `10.0.0.0/24`. But `177.0.0.0/24` would only be shortened to `177.0/24`, because that would be a Class B network, so the second octet is assumed to be significant.
- If the netmask matches what it would've been under the old system, OR if it's a "host" routing entry, the CIDR suffix gets omitted. For example, `169.254` is short for `169.254.0.0/16` because `169` is in the Class B range.

That's a bit complicated, but translating it back to a full listing is easy: if it doesn't list a CIDR suffix, it's just 8 times the number of octets explicitly listed (or /32 for host entries); and if there aren't 4 octets listed, add ".0"s to the address part as needed. For example, `169.254` -> `169.254/16` -> `169.254.0.0/16`.

Comment: It seems that when it omits the CIDR suffix, that's because the network happens to match the historical _classful_ network sizes. For example, 169.254.0.0 used to be in Class B, and Class B meant /16. Quite a few BSD-derived network tools (netstat, route) still have old assumptions about address classes built into them.

Comment: As for when /32 is dropped, that seems to happen for route entries with _hardware addresses_ – the system uses a single table for both IP routes and ARP cache entries, which again seems to be common on BSD systems. The latter are by definition for a single host only, so the tool probably omits /32 because it can be inferred from the `H` and `L` flags.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. What you say sounds likely, but it would be good to verify it with a manual or source code. I looked online but I couldn't find any manual explaining the BSD IP address notation. Do you know where I could find it?

Comment: @grawity Hah! It looks like you're right. I'll investigate in more detail, and update my answer later today.